# REST API PowerShell Array response

Tags: rest, powershell

Using PowerShell `Invoke-RestMethod` to query a REST and getting back a response as shown below:

```
REST> Write-Host $response
@{Success=}

REST> Write-Host $response.Success
@{count=1; uri=https://useful}
```

I would like to be able to assign `uri` to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the uri using:

```
$yourVariable = $response.Success.uri
```